# Error al llamar por segunda vez una función

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo este error en consola tras ejecutar por segunda vez esta función, desconozco su origen, si alguno de los usuarios de esta web puede colaborarme seria de gran ayuda.

Adjunto la función:

```
$scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados = function (ID_EMPLEADO) {
    PagoEmpleadosS.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados(ID_EMPLEADO, function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            var resps = response.datos;
            $scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados = resps;

            $.each($scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados, function (index, value) {
                $scope.operacion.SUMA += value.TOTAL_PAGAR;
                $scope.operacion.PAGO = value.PAGO;
                $scope.operacion.PORCENTAJE = value.PAGO / value.TOTAL_PAGAR * 100;
            })

            $("#ModalDetalleServicios2").modal("show");
            $("#ConsultarEmpleadosPagados").modal("hide");
        }
    })
}
```

El error que sale en consola al ejecutarlo por segunda vez es éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: llamar por segunda vez? a que te refieres, puedes decribir el contexto porfavor

Comment: Si te fijas en la linea `$scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados = resps;`, estas pisando la definición de la función con un arrelgo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defines `$scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados = function (){}` y mas adelante le cambias el valor a `$scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados = resps;`. No puedes hacer eso, `ngClick` espera una funcion.

Si lo que quieres es guardar el valor de `resps`, deberías crear otra variable para eso:

```
$scope.response = [];
$scope.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados = function (ID_EMPLEADO) {
    PagoEmpleadosS.Servicios_EmpleadosPagados(ID_EMPLEADO, function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            var resps = response.datos;
            $scope.response = resps;

            $.each($scope.response, function (index, value) {
            //..
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he solucionado cambiándole de nombre a la función.